# Use time or frame number for still image in FFmpeg filter

Tags: ffmpeg, video-editing

I'm trying to do a transition from image `a.jpg` to image `b.jpg` using FFmpeg filter. But it seems that FFmpeg won't recognize any time related options for still images, and the frame number I get is always zero.

The example command is as follows:

```
TIME=15 && ffmpeg -loop 1 -t ${TIME} -i a.jpg -loop 1 -t ${TIME} -i b.jpg -filter_complex "
[0:v]crop=w=(t)/${TIME}*iw:x=0[a_crop];
[1:v][a_crop]overlay[out]" -map "[out]" -t ${TIME} ab.mp4
```

output:

```
Error when evaluating the expression '(t)/15*iw'
```

```
TIME=15 && ffmpeg -loop 1 -t ${TIME} -i a.jpg -loop 1 -t ${TIME} -i b.jpg -filter_complex "
[0:v]crop=w=((n+10)/60)/${TIME}*iw:x=0[a_crop];
[1:v][a_crop]overlay[out]" -map "[out]" -t ${TIME} ab.mp4
```

The command would work, but the video is not moving, I suspect that the n is always `0`.

Thanks!

Comment: Exprs for `w` and `h` in crop can't be animated, only `x` and `y`. Consider looking at the xfade filter.

Comment: @Gyan That makes a lot of sense! Thanks! Do you happen to know if there is a way to use Xfade with duration longer than 60 seconds?

Comment: Only using hacks - basically, rescale timestamps before and then restore them afterwards.